# Obtaining login scripts for a domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have read that a useful technique in penetration testing is to obtain the login scripts for a domain, as they may often have passwords obfuscated in there or other useful information.

However, in my research, the only way I have found to do this is by using the following command:

```
smbclient -W DOMAIN-U ‘user’ \\\\TARGET\\SYSVOL
mget policies
```

A lot of the time this doesn't work, as SYSVOL results in an error message that network name is not found. Is this the only way to obtain login scripts, or are there alternative methods?

This is assuming I have credentials, of course.

Comment: Sysvol only exists on domain controllers, sure you are trying this in the right context?